# maven-assembly-plugin: do not trigger search of default assembly descriptor

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have maven-assembly-plugin configured to build 2 zip artifacts:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skipAssembly>true</skipAssembly>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>game-zip</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skipAssembly>false</skipAssembly>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>${basedir}/assembly/game-zip.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <finalName>game-</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>lib-zip</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skipAssembly>false</skipAssembly>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>${basedir}/assembly/lib-zip.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <finalName>lib-</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I run it using: **clean package assembly:single**.
This configuration works well, however it requires 3 explicit tags **skipAssembly**. The one in the root should be **true**, because if not - build will fail (however, after expected job done). 
Log:

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (game-zip) @ gdxg-art ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: D:\idea\gdxg5/assembly/game-zip.xml
[INFO] Building zip: D:\idea\gdxg5\target\game-.zip
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (lib-zip) @ gdxg-art ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: D:\idea\gdxg5/assembly/lib-zip.xml
[INFO] Building zip: D:\idea\gdxg5\target\lib-.zip
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) @ gdxg-art
```

Last maven-assembly-plugin invocation fails with: **Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project gdxg-art: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found**.

Question: is there any way to avoid explicit skipAssembly=true/false settings? Because it looks like some overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is due to the fact that you run maven using `clean package assembly:single`. Your `maven-assembly-plugin` is already configured to run the task `assembly:single` on the phase `package`of the maven lifecycle.

And this *small* error in the tasks you are calling is causing this mess in the build cycle.

Instead of running `clean package assembly:single` and use just `clean package`, you won't need the three skipAssembly that you set.

I created a bug ticket on the `maven-assembly-plugin` JIRA because I think that this behavior is not normal (even if the usage would prefer that we use `clean package` and not `clean package assembly:single`) : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-763

Comment: you are right! I run clean package without skipAssembly parameters and only game-zip, lib-zip descriptors has been triggered (no default-cli).

Comment: In my opinion it should normally work when your run `clean package assembly:single`, because when you do the same with `clean package jar:jar` it works so why not with the assembly ?